# ssh -ing and compiling the java program

Tags: java, shell, ssh

Hello I need to ssh in one ip address and run my java code through shell script
I do it by this way

```
ssh $LINE java -Djava.library.path=/N/u/sbpatil/ds/Project4/demons/Project4Lib -cp "/N/u/sbpatil/ds/Project4/demons:/N/u/sbpatil/ds/Project4/demons/Project4Lib/jug-uuid.jar:/N/u/sbpatil/ds/Project4/demons/Project4Lib/NaradaBrokering.jar:/N/u/sbpatil/ds/Project4/demons/Project4Lib/sigar.jar" PublisherClient >> output2 &
```

but output2 file has no output whatsoever.Even if the run command of java is giving me an error,that error should be written in that file.,buts it is not being written.
Can anybody please tell me how should i write this script?

Comment: instead of doing everything in one line, can you first just ssh-login to the remote machine, and then start the java command there? It might make it easier to debug as then it's clear which part of the command happen on which machine, e.g. I don't know if that `>>` is done on the remote machine or on yours...

Comment: errors won't be written to the output file unless you do something like 2>&1 before the final &; otherwise output2 will only contain the standard output.

Comment: actually the file is a shared file system so >> command will make a file accessible to all the nodes..

Comment: Also I tried 
ssh ipAddress pwd
pwd

first pwd will be of ssh
but 2nd pwd of the head node which is before i had done ssh

Answer (score 2):

Now it looks like you run ssh in the background, redirecting output into local file.
Enclose the command line into '': `ssh $LINE 'java ... 1>>output2 2>&1 &'`

Also using `nohup` might be a good idea if you launch your app like that.

Comment: 2>&1 redirects STDERR (System.err in Java, where for example stacktraces are printed by default) into STDOUT (System.out, where you normally print). So by doing `2>&1` you capture all possible output in the same file. Obviously you may write to different files, but generally when launching background process it is a good idea to redirect both.